# I need to change my calendar format to start and end on the 23rd of each month (financial month)

Tags: javascript, c#, date

I'm working on a project where I need to change the months format to start on the 23rd and then end on the 23rd again.

Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Be more precise. What calendar control are you using?

Comment: its for a graph graph. so i need to set a variable with the specific date each month , but i need to do it in plain C#. not really Javascript(only if i really have to).     the graph sould be from the 23rd to the 23rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are really asking. In C#, dates can be expressed with the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) struct. For example:

```
int startYear = 2017;
int startMonth = 2;
int startDay = 23;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
//
int endYear = 2017;
int endMonth = 3;
int endDay = 23;
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(endYear, endMonth, endDay);
```

If this does not help, then try looking at [Working with Calendars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x(v=vs.110).aspx).

If no answer helps you, then you need to provide more info. For example, try posting the code you are working with. You don't need to post the entire project, just the snippet or perhaps class(es) that you have issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX Calender Extender. Here is the Sample Markup Code:

```
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ControlIDHere" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                        TargetControlID="TextBoxIDHere" PopupButtonID="CalenderImageIDHere" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
 </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

you can also initialize the StartDate and EndDate in CalendarExtender.

Hope Helps.